# How to have two Flexible items in a Row flex adaptively?

Tags: flutter

I have a Row with 2 flexible texts inside.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(child: Text('blah')),
    Flexible(child: Text('blah')),
  ],
);
```

I want to figure out how to make it so that:

- When both items are short, align item 1 to start and item 2 to end.
- When item 1 is long and wants to take up more width than its flex bound - allow this as long as item 2 is not taking up that space (and vice versa)
- When both items are long, respect the flex bound and maintain the 1:1 flex ratio.

I've tried various combinations of `Expanded`, `Flexible`, and `MainAxisAlignment` values in the `Row` but can't seem to figure out how to reproduce the above requirements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is complex enough that manual layout is needed.
`Boxy` package is good choice. You can also do it without package, but since `MultiChildLayoutDelegate` doesn't expose `Intrinsic` of its children, you need to make your own `RenderBox` and it would need a lot of boilerplate

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:boxy/boxy.dart';

class MyRowStack extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyRowStack({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 300,
      child: ListView(
        children: const [
          MyLayout(leftChild: Short(), rightChild: Short()),
          MyLayout(leftChild: Short(), rightChild: Long()),
          MyLayout(leftChild: Long(), rightChild: Short()),
          MyLayout(leftChild: Long(), rightChild: Long()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Long extends StatelessWidget {
  const Long({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green[400],
      child: const Text(
        "Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Short extends StatelessWidget {
  const Short({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue[400],
      child: const Text(
        "Ipsum",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyLayout(
      {super.key, required this.leftChild, required this.rightChild});
  final Widget leftChild;
  final Widget rightChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBoxy(
      delegate: MyLayoutDelegate(),
      children: [
        leftChild,
        rightChild,
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyLayoutDelegate extends BoxyDelegate {
  MyLayoutDelegate();
  @override
  Size layout() {
    final leftChild = children[0];
    final rightChild = children[1];
    final width = constraints.maxWidth;
      // Get prefered width of children
    final leftPrefered =
        leftChild.render.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(constraints.maxHeight);
    final rightPrefered =
        rightChild.render.getMaxIntrinsicWidth(constraints.maxHeight);
    if (leftPrefered + rightPrefered <= width) {
      // Both are small, give them their prefered size
      leftChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: leftPrefered,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
      rightChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: rightPrefered,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
    } else if (leftPrefered <= width / 2) {
      // Left is small
      leftChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: leftPrefered,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
      // Give right the rest of space
      rightChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: width - leftChild.size.width,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
    } else if (rightPrefered <= width / 2) {
      // Right is small
      rightChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: rightPrefered,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
      // Give left the rest of space
      leftChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: width - rightChild.size.width,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Both are big, give them half of the space
      leftChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: width / 2,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
      rightChild.layout(
        BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: width / 2,
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
      );
    }
    final height = max(leftChild.size.height, rightChild.size.height);
    // space out in MainAxis, center in CrossAxis
    leftChild.position(Offset(0, (height - leftChild.size.height) / 2));
    rightChild.position(Offset(
        width - rightChild.size.width, (height - rightChild.size.height) / 2));
    return Size(width, height);
  }
}
```